# How to select only every n-th row in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table.It has more than 100 row and increasing.
I want to get rows like this :

```
1  - row (not needed 2,3,4,5,6,7. rows)
8  - row  
15 - row
22 - row
29 - row
```

note : at MSSQL 2008 R2

Comment: show you table schema please

Comment: *Why* do you want to get your rows like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and [`%`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx), f.e. with a `common-table-expression`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT t.*, RN= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By OrderColumn ASC)
  FROM dbo.TableName t
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN % 7 = 1
```

Comment: Yesss. Thank you so much Tim.

Answer (score 0):

--It Helps to you

```
CREATE TABLE ##Numeric (Id INT)

DECLARE @Value INT = 1

WHILE (@Value <= 100)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ##Numeric
    SELECT @Value

    SET @Value = @Value + 1
END

SELECT *
FROM ##Numeric
WHERE ID % 7 = 1
```